# Windows 8 grid app template - adding data dynamically

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I want to dynamically add data into data.js in my JavaScript Windows 8 app based on the grid app template. I want some particular group items in that template to scroll from right to left. And also how to flip images of particular tile inside the group items?

Answer (score 0):

For the question of adding data dynamically, I would check out the following samples:

- [HTML ListView loading behaviors sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-loading-behaviors-718a4673)
- [HTML ListView optimizing performance sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-performance-39fb71f0)

More samples may be found at: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps

For the latter question, I'd suggest posting a separate question on the image manipulation, with some additional detail on what you're trying to do.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).